# Time scale calculus vs Lebesgue–Stieltjes calculus

Tags: integration, tag-removed, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

About the same time, it seems, as I asked [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43792/riemann-stieltjes-derivative), a new post appeared on the wikipedia discussion page for [Time scale calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_scale_calculus) which suggests the Time scale derivative (aka Hilger derivative aka delta-derivative) is the same as the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon-Nikodym_derivative) of the [Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration).

Do you agree that the time scale delta-derivative is a Lebesgue–Stieltjes derivative with the appropriate weight function? (The notion of Lebesgue–Stieltjes derivative being similarly defined to the Riemann-Stieltjes derivative of my previous question.)

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago a paper was uploaded to the arXiv which answers this question:

"On the connection between the Hilger and Radon--Nikodym derivatives" 
by Jonathan Eckhardt and Gerald Teschl

http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2511